# Android: if onOptionsItemSelected return false crashes the app

Tags: android

After a long time I'm back to android programming to continue from my newbee position up!

Before, this code worked for me in my main activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_do_task) {
        updateDisplay("Task done!");
      }
      return false;
    }
```

now I must only implement it this way:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      int id = item.getItemId();
      if (id == R.id.action_do_task) {
        doIt("done!");
      }
      //return false;
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

If I use return false, the program hangs and from the error messages I can not figure it out why it is that way.

Yet in the Android help I read that as default, super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); will also return false, so why it happens this way? Why the program crashes if I hand code a return false?

Could anybody please help to understand this?

Comment: I tried returning false in my program its working fine , comment out the line doIt("done!"); and then try I think error is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resource Ids's type is long.** You should declare the id variable as long type.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    long id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_do_task) {
        doIt("done!");
    }
    return false;
    //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```